# Dynamically add code to JS

Tags: javascript, dynamic, graph

I've been asked to create Graphs dynamically according to a certain csv content.

I'm currently using the `Chart.js` library, which requires you to add elements to the "label" property in order to properly build the graph.

```
label : ["name1", "name2"]
```

What I am not able to do here, is dynamically add the elements contained in an array "Names" into the parameter.

```
var names = "asia", "africa";
```

What I am try to accomplish is that, according to the number of entries inside the array "names", those many names are gonna appear on the graph.

Any ideas? thanks in advance!

[EDIT]

```
function createChart(upData, lData, allData){

        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
            document.getElementById("myChart").style.width = "<?wsx5 document.write(parameters.widthsize.value);?>px";
            document.getElementById("myChart").style.height = "<?wsx5 document.write(parameters.heightsize.value);?>px";


            var data = {
                labels: [

                ],
```

This is about what I got now, the relevant part of course. upData is an array that contains the names I need, and those elements need to be added dynamically to the label section

Comment: You should be able to use *label: names* if you have put the entires into names before you attempt to build the graph. We might be able to help you more if you would show some sample code to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Title is missleading.

Comment: I can tell you that by adding "names" (which is the array name) under labels, as in "label : names", all names will be displayed as if it was just one entry

Comment: This is not an array: `var names = "asia", "africa";`. To be an array it should go with brackets: `var names = ["asia", "africa"];`

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out what the problem was.
Apparently the code in order for the labels field to work is without brackets:

```
function createChart(upData, lData, allData){

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
        document.getElementById("myChart").style.width = "<?wsx5 document.write(parameters.widthsize.value);?>px";
        document.getElementById("myChart").style.height = "<?wsx5 document.write(parameters.heightsize.value);?>px";


        var data = {
            labels: arrayname , }
```